# Problem in measuring potential because of oscilloscope's input impedance

Tags: oscilloscope, input-impedance

I am trying to use a sensor, whose resistance value change from infinity to around 10kΩ when variable load is applied. The load is applied for a small duration and in order to capture that I'm using TDS6000 series oscilloscope. I'm trying to use a potential divider circuit as shown below (Rs- resistance of sensor).

On multi-meter I'm able to get voltage range of 0-1.6V across R1, but on oscilloscope I'm barely able to get a few mV. This is likely because of the input impedance of the oscilloscope (Ro=50Ω), which makes the net resistance of lower part (A-GND) very small as compared to Rs.

I have tried a couple of combinations of resistors but haven't got any success yet. I want the variable voltage in the range of 0-1.5V. Does anyone have any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Your oscilloscope doesn't have a high impedance option?  Edit:  I see, it is an optional accessory.

Comment: +Measuring depends on distance, capacitance and inductance of cables. Define your problem in more detail. Why can't you use an INA?

Comment: Your schematic has some errors. What is 60.1?  Does 3V get grounded on -ve side?

Answer (score 2):

Use a unity gain opamp that has the bandwidth
Maybe use an opamp as a buffer, the opamp will need to have more bandwidth than the sensor (and will add in an voltage offset error Vos, so select an opamp with a low voltage offset). The opamp will also need to be able to source more than ~8mA on the output.

Another option would be to use an opamp with gain.

You might also want to know that there are many [eval boards such as this](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/sparkfun-configurable-opamp-board-tsh82/85360) to make adding an opamp for test easier. Almost all manufacturers provide eval boards for opamps also.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSJSZJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Borrow an active_probe, with 1Megohm Rin (or even 10Megohm), that will drive a 50 Ohm load (this will a high-speed probe).